# Why isn't PHP loading the SQLite extension?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm sure it's something simple. I've got a PHP 5.2.17 installation on Windows 7 with the `extension=php_pdo.dll` and `extension=php_sqlite.dll` lines uncommented in the ini, but `phpinfo()` still shows nothing about SQLite being loaded.

I know it's pulling the correct ini file, because I changed `short_open_tag` to "On" and it was reflected in the phpinfo dump.

I tried changing `extension_dir` to `./`, `./ext`, and `./ext/` to no avail.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after changing ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the full pathname for the extension directory:

```
extension_dir = "D:/php/ext"
```